# Performing set operations using linux command

Tags: linux, sed

I have the following two lists of numbers stored in two different files:

```
File A:
7
1
2
9

File B:
10
8
4
9
```

Now I want to find out the set operation A-B (i.e. find only those numbers that are in A but not in B). Is there some way by which I may do the same using linux command (like sed). I know it is possible to do it using python, but I am just curious to know if it is possible to do the same using some linux command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple, almost-working version is this:

```
grep -v -f file2 file1
```

That is, use lines from `file2` as patterns; match them in `file1` and print the ones not found (i.e. `file1 - file2`).  However, what if `file1` contains `10` and `file2` contains `1`?  Then we have a problem because substrings are matched too.  We can fix it this way:

```
grep -v -f <(sed 's/\(.*\)/^\1$/' file2) file1
```

That is, preprocess `file2` to prepend `^` and append `$` so the matching occurs against entire lines, not substrings in `file1`.

Answer (score 0):

`diff` is the tool for this:

```
diff f1 f2
1,3c1,3
< 7
< 1
< 2
---
> 10
> 8
> 4
```

f1 has this unique number `7,1,2`
f2 has this unique number `10,8,4`